# How to write a procedure without handing over the parameters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a procedure with four parameters, one parameter is required but 3 others are not required.

The procedure looks something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p_choose_vehicle_byGroup_resultCount_Radiant5
    @IdCustomer int,
    @idGroupVehicle int = null,
    @ResultCount int= null,
    @Radiant int= null 
AS
    DECLARE @start geography
    SET @start = (SELECT location FROM Customer WHERE idCustomer = @idCustomer)

    IF @ResultCount IS NULL AND @idGroupVehicle IS NULL AND @Radiant IS NULL
        SELECT 
            idVehicle, idGroupVehicle, brand, model, maxRange, weight, 
            maxSpeed, nameLocation, @start.STDistance(locationVehicle) / 1000 AS distanceInKm
        FROM
            Vehicle 
        WHERE 
            (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle) / 1000 IS NOT NULL)
        ORDER BY 
            @start.STDistance(locationVehicle) / 1000 ASC
    else if @ResultCount is null and @Radiant is null
    select  idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation , @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 as distanceInKm
        from Vehicle 
            where  idGroupVehicle= @idGroupVehicle and (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000  is not null)
            order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
    else if @Radiant is null
    select TOP(@ResultCount) idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation , @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 as distanceInKm
        from Vehicle 
            where idGroupVehicle= @idGroupVehicle  and  (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000  is not null)
            order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
    else
    select TOP(@ResultCount) idVehicle,idGroupVehicle,brand,model,maxRange,weight,maxSpeed, nameLocation , @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 as distanceInKm
        from Vehicle 
            where idGroupVehicle= @idGroupVehicle  and  (@start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000  <= @Radiant)
            order by @start.STDistance(locationVehicle)/1000 asc
GO
```

This procedure work but my question is is any way to improve this procedure because when I want exec p_choose_vehicle_byGroup_resultCount_Radiant5 1 is good 1,1, is good but when I try choose idCustomer and resultCount I must do this 1,null,1 but I want to not write null and choose this option is any way to improve this procedure ?

Comment: There is no option in sql which allows you to specify which parameters you are passing values to - you could create 1 parameter as a string and pass all input values as 1 set of concatenated key value pairs and burst them in the proc- but that doesn't look like an improvement to me

Comment: @P.Salmon What are you talking about `exec p_choose_vehicle_byGroup_resultCount_Radiant5 1, @ResultCount = 1;` works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am not understanding, you just need to call your procedure like

```
exec p_choose_vehicle_byGroup_resultCount_Radiant5 @IdCustomer=1, @resultCount=1
```